# Zmq setup for VS2010 C++

Tags: zeromq

I am trying to setup zmq for VS2010 C++.

Following are the steps I have tried:

1. Downloaded `.zip` source
2. Built the solution `builds\msvc\msvc10.sln`
3. Set C/C++ > General > **Additional Include Dictionaries** -> `C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 3.2.3\include`
4. Set Linker > General > **Additional Library Dictionaries**  -> `C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 3.2.3\lib`
5. Set Linker > Input > **Additional Dependencies** -> `libzmq.lib`

And yet getting this error:

**`"Cannot open include file: 'zmq.hpp': No such file or directory"`**

Can anyone please help me with right steps?

Comment: There's a zmq.h, there's no zmq.hpp in the standard zmq distribution.

Comment: @nos First I got .hpp from distribution which in-turn is including .h file. When I try to include zmq.h file its not even recognizing zmq code.